# Select the last record for the date and time columns

Tags: t-sql, select, where-clause, exists

I need to select the last record in the academic table which has two columns for date and time. When I run the query I get an error. Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

```
USE PCUnitTest
SELECT        C.ACCOUNTNO, C.CONTACT, C.LASTNAME, C.KEY4, A.PEOPLE_ID, A.APP_STATUS, A.APP_DECISION, A.REVISION_DATE, A.REVISION_TIME
FROM            ACADEMIC AS A INNER JOIN
                         GM.dbo.CONTACT1 AS C ON A.PEOPLE_ID = C.KEY4
WHERE A.REVISION_DATE = (SELECT     TOP (1) REVISION_DATE, REVISION_TIME, PEOPLE_CODE, PEOPLE_ID, PEOPLE_CODE_ID, ACADEMIC_YEAR, ACADEMIC_TERM, ACADEMIC_SESSION, PROGRAM, DEGREE, CURRICULUM
FROM         PCUnitTest.dbo.ACADEMIC
ORDER BY REVISION_DATE DESC, REVISION_TIME DESC)
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP (1) REVISION_DATE, REVISION_TIME,...` selects more than one column which you're going to assign to `A.REVISION_DATE`. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, but the time and date are in separate columns and the time is dependent on the date. Would it be where date = something, and where time = something?

Comment: That academic table has 7 keys and I need to select the last record and update the status column for the PEOPLE_ID by REVISION_DATE, REVISION_TIME. That academic table has 7 keys PEOPLE_CODE_ID, ACADEMIC_YEAR, ACADEMIC_TERM, ACADEMIC_SESSION, PROGRAM, DEGREE, CURRICULUM

Comment: Thanks, yes the query completes if i have only the one revision_date column, but the time is dependent on the date, would I just add another and where revision time subquery.

Comment: Then I have, 
WHERE A.REVISION_DATE = (SELECT TOP (1) REVISION_DATE
FROM         PowerCampusUnitTest.dbo.ACADEMIC
ORDER BY REVISION_DATE DESC, REVISION_TIME DESC)
AND
A.REVISION_TIME = (SELECT TOP (1) REVISION_TIME
FROM         PowerCampusUnitTest.dbo.ACADEMIC
ORDER BY REVISION_DATE DESC, REVISION_TIME DESC) I'll test it with some data to see if it returns the right row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Join the query you are using in the where

```
USE PowerCampusUnitTest
SELECT C.ACCOUNTNO, C.CONTACT, C.LASTNAME, C.KEY4, A.PEOPLE_ID, A.APP_STATUS, A.APP_DECISION, A.REVISION_DATE, A.REVISION_TIME
FROM ACADEMIC AS A 
INNER JOIN GoldMineUnitTest.dbo.CONTACT1 AS C 
ON A.PEOPLE_ID = C.KEY4
INNER JOIN (
SELECT TOP 1 A2.REVISION_DATE,A2.REVISION_TIME FROM PowerCampusUnitTest.dbo.ACADEMIC A2
ORDER BY REVISION_DATE DESC, REVISION_TIME DESC
)AS A2 
ON A.REVISION_DATE = A2.REVISION_DATE AND A.REVISION_TIME = A2.REVISION_TIME
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER()

```
USE PCUnitTest

SELECT
 R.ACCOUNTNO, R.CONTACT, R.LASTNAME, R.KEY4, R.PEOPLE_ID, R.APP_STATUS, R.APP_DECISION, R.REVISION_DATE, R.REVISION_TIME
FROM
(
SELECT        C.ACCOUNTNO, C.CONTACT, C.LASTNAME, C.KEY4, A.PEOPLE_ID, A.APP_STATUS, A.APP_DECISION, A.REVISION_DATE, A.REVISION_TIME
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.REVISION_DATE DESC, A.REVISION_TIME DESC) RN
FROM            ACADEMIC AS A INNER JOIN
                         GMUnitTest.dbo.CONTACT1 AS C ON A.PEOPLE_ID = C.KEY4
) R
WHERE RN=1
```

If you want to get the latest row for each PEOPLE_ID, then add  PARTITION BY

```
SELECT
 R.ACCOUNTNO, R.CONTACT, R.LASTNAME, R.KEY4, R.PEOPLE_ID, R.APP_STATUS, R.APP_DECISION, R.REVISION_DATE, R.REVISION_TIME
FROM
(
SELECT        C.ACCOUNTNO, C.CONTACT, C.LASTNAME, C.KEY4, A.PEOPLE_ID, A.APP_STATUS, A.APP_DECISION, A.REVISION_DATE, A.REVISION_TIME
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.PEOPLE_ID ORDER BY A.REVISION_DATE DESC, A.REVISION_TIME DESC) RN
FROM            ACADEMIC AS A INNER JOIN
                         GMUnitTest.dbo.CONTACT1 AS C ON A.PEOPLE_ID = C.KEY4
) R
WHERE RN=1
```